# woocommerce_checkout_create_order hook not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WooCommerce functionality within WordPress and have encountered an issue with the woocommerce_checkout_create_order hook. My aim is to execute a function during the order creation process, but it seems that the hook is not being triggered. Here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
   add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 1, 2);


function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order, $data) {
    error_log('test',print_r($order,true));

    if (WC()->session->__isset('custom_form_data')) {
        $custom_data = WC()->session->get('custom_form_data');


        $order->update_meta_data('_custom_form_data', $custom_data);

        $meta_data = $order->get_meta('_custom_form_data');
       

        WC()->session->__unset('custom_form_data');
    } else {
    }
}
```

I expected the line error_log('test', print_r($order, true)); to log information in the error logs, but there is no entry, suggesting that the woocommerce_checkout_create_order hook is not being triggered.

Additional information:

- I am using the latest version of WooCommerce.
- Other error_log calls
  in my code work correctly.
- When I attach the same function to a
  simpler hook, like wp_footer, it works fine.
- I've also checked for
  conflicts with other plugins and themes, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the block checkout, `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` is not triggered.

Use:

```
woocommerce_store_api_checkout_order_processed
```

or

```
woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_meta
```

in **woocommerce/src/StoreApi/Routes/V1/Checkout.php**